# How can I take these arrays and use them to populate the fields of a structure?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, struct

I have several vectors, and would like to use them to populate fields in a structure array. The vectors will only ever have one of two lengths - either they will be of length N, or of length 1. For example, if N=3 my vectors might look like the following:

```
a = [0 5 7]
b = [-2 6 8]
c = 6
d = [11 12 13]
e = 20
```

I would like the result to be

```
my_structure(1).a = 0
my_structure(2).a = 5
my_structure(3).a = 7

my_structure(1).b = -2
my_structure(2).b = 6
my_structure(3).b = 8

my_structure(1).c = 6
my_structure(2).c = 6
my_structure(3).c = 6

my_structure(1).d = 11
my_structure(2).d = 12
my_structure(3).d = 13

my_structure(1).e = 20
my_structure(2).e = 20
my_structure(3).e = 20
```

You can see that for vectors which only initially have length=1, that every element of the structure array should have this same value.

Is there a succinct way to achieve this without having to loop over every element? It should be extendable so that I can add more vectors f,g,h,... if required.

As queried in the comments, I cannot simply use `my_structure.a = [0 5 7]`, etc, because I need to be able to pass `my_structure(i)` to another function, which requires that each field contains only a single value (not an array).

Comment: Looping is much more succinct than hand-writing like this. It is a fallacy that looping is slow in MATLAB, especially since the latest JIT update. Why doesn't looping suit your purposes?

Comment: I don't want to hand write like this - I only write it to show what I would like the result of each query to be.

Comment: @Adriaan I know that there are these arrayfun() and structfun() functions in Matlab, so I suspect there is a neat way to use them to do this. I am not at all worried about looping being slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Turns out you can take advantage of this line from the docs:

> If any of the value inputs is a nonscalar **cell array**, then `s` has the same dimensions as that cell array.

So

```
N = 3;          % Each var has 1 or N elements

a = [0 5 7];    
b = [-2 6 8];
c = 6;

% Create an anonymous function to make all vars the correct size CELL (1 or N)
pad = @(x) num2cell( repmat(x, 1, N/numel(x)) );
strct = struct( 'a', pad(a), 'b', pad(b), 'c', pad(c) );
```

This follows a similar thought pattern to the original answer below, but is obviously much more concise.

---

**Original answer**

<strike>The easiest</strike> *A verbose* way to do this would be to start with a scalar structure, and turn it into a structure array. So...

```
N = 3;          % Each var has 1 or N elements

a = [0 5 7];    
b = [-2 6 8];
c = 6;

% Create an anonymous function to make all vars the correct size (1 or N)
pad = @(x) repmat(x, 1, N/numel(x));
% Create the scalar struct with padding
strctA = struct( 'a', pad(a), 'b', pad(b), 'c', pad(c) );
```

Then you can have a loop to convert this to a structure array, which has no ties to the variable names and so is easier to maintain:

```
f = fieldnames(strctA);  % Get the field names, i.e. the original variable names
strctB = struct([]);     % Create an output struct. The [] input makes it a struct array
for iFn = 1:numel(f)     % Loop over the fields
    for n = 1:N          % Loop over the array elements
        strctB(n).(f{iFn}) = strctA.(f{iFn})(n); % Assign to new structure
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This achieves what I wanted, but is a little more cumbersome than I had anticipated. I thought it might be able to be done without loops using arrayfun() or structfun(), resulting in fewer lines of code, but your solution even uses two nested loops. Maybe "easiest" and "succinct" are two different things.

Comment: @teeeeee Please see my edit, turns out I was close but there is a much simpler answer.

Comment: Fantastic, good find - I have learnt something!  Seems like even if you omit the pad() function from c when creating the structure it still works. Although better to keep it for generaliy I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @teeeeee Yes scalars will get copied/distributed, but you have to convert all of the arrays to cells or they will also just get copied/distributed. I wrote the `pad` function so that it worked in both cases and you don't have to care what size the input variables are. You could use this for the same result if you didn't want the generality: `struct( 'a', num2cell(a), 'b', num2cell(b), 'c', c )`

Answer (score 0):

Wolfie's answer is really clever, but you could also use a more straight forward solution using a single for loop:

```
N = 3;

a = [0 5 7]
b = [-2 6 8]
c = 6
d = [11 12 13]
e = 20

for i = 1:N
    my_structure(i).a = a(min(length(a), i))
    my_structure(i).b = b(min(length(b), i))
    my_structure(i).c = c(min(length(c), i))
    my_structure(i).d = d(min(length(d), i))
    my_structure(i).e = e(min(length(e), i))
end
```

The advantage of this approach is that your code is easier readable.